# How do I perform different dunks on NBA Jam?

Tags: nba-jam-2010

Is there some control over which dunk is performed or does it solely depend on the direction/timing of the dunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always been under the impression that the style of dunk performed is based entirely on your speed, angle, and timing of pressing the dunk button.  Looking at [some](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/NBA_Jam_%282010%29/Controls) [guides](http://www.gamefly.com/game/Wii/NBA-Jam/143075/GameplayControls/) online, there is likewise no mention of dunk control.